# Alternative for [].forEach.call(...) in ECMA6Script

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I use the following code in all my applications to enumerate through DOM elements:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');
[].forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
    div.style.color = 'green';
});
```

This code works, however `[].forEach.call(...)` is not easy to read in large applications. Is there a native way for easier DOM enumeration in ECMA6Script without using custom-made functions or prototypes?

Comment: *"...without using custom-made functions or prototypes?"* Why not? Why not have your own `forEach`: `var forEach = function() { var f = Array.prototype.forEach; return function(target, callback, thisArg) { return f.call(target, callback, thisArg); }; }();` Then you just use `forEach(elements, function(element) { ... })` (and you don't create and throw away temporary arrays, as your current code is doing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wouldn't use `forEach` at all any more in ES6. You'd use a [`for of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```
for (let div of document.querySelectorAll('div'))
    div.style.color = 'green';
```

Apart from that, you can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to cast an iterable object to an array and then invoke `.forEach` on that; but in fact with the upcoming DOM spec this is unnecessary where `querySelectorAll` will return an `Elements` collection that does inherit from `Array` in the ES6 way - so you can call the `.forEach` method directly on it!

Comment: This is even cooler and saves you from using a (slower) callback. Forgot `for...of` could be used for `NodeList` objects too.

Comment: For me, this doesn't work. I don't believe NodeLists are iterators. What environment did this work in for you? I get `TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...)[Symbol.iterator] is not a function`.

Comment: @torazaburo: They're not? I didn't test, it could well be that they aren't yet (and the spec should definitely be changed if it hasn't already). A simple fix would be `NodeList.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator];`.

Comment: @torazaburo: Seems like [support is definitely planned](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=229398). [WebIDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/) doesn't mention iteration at all, but DOM is going to get a completely new [`Elements` interface that subclasses `Array`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#element-collections)

Comment: @Bergi Interesting, thanks for the pointer, glad to see that is in the works. Munging the NodeList prototype as you proposed worked but isn't it at all scary? In any case, shouldn't you tweak your answer?

Comment: you might also want to use `let` instead of `var` to ensure that the variable is scoped to the loop body

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("div")[Symbol.iterator]` works in firefox, but that might be a browser-specific extension of NodeList

Comment: @MaxArt: *"This is even cooler and saves you from using a (slower) callback."* I wouldn't make any statements about performance yet. `for...of` actually has to call the `.next` method of iterator and check for exceptions from / the end of the iterator.

Comment: @FelixKling: But we can expect this to be heavily optimised for native iterators. In fact an `ArrayIterator::next` never throws, not more than an old `{ let iteratedObject = …; for (let i=0; i<iteratedObject.length; i++) … }` did.

Comment: @Bergi: Fair enough. Of course I hope browsers will optimize these cases. I just wouldn't make any statements about perf just yet :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
Array.from(elements).forEach(elem => ...)
```

Comment: Yes, this is completely ES6. Anyway, Gecko-based browsers have these array method generics like `Array.forEach` that may become handy in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

In ES6 you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('div')].forEach(e => console.log(e))
```