# Is there an alternative to the for loop when looping through DOM elements

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I recently read that many developers have stopped using the `for` loop, it seems that I'm wrong in using it all the time.

I did a bit of research and it seems that methods like `map` are quicker to write. Whilst I need to work through all the available array methods, a method to do the following I can't find.

Say we have a bunch of quotes and we want to create something with them

```
var quotes = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote');

for(var i = 0; i < quote.length; i++){
  console.log(quotes[i])
}
```

Is there a way to do this without the `for` loop

Comment: what are you planning to do?

Comment: Using for loop is not an evil thing.

Comment: `for (var quote of document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote')) console.log(quote)` or `[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote'), console.log, console)` would be alternatives for what you are doing here.

Comment: @Bergi I was about to suggest spread operator to OP. But while checking(`[...document.querySelector(".something")]`) it with nodeList, it is throwing an error. Can't we use spread operator at this context?

Comment: @DanielA.White nothing, I just read a comment that said most developers no longer use the `for` loop, so I wanted to know if there is an alternative for this use case.

Comment: See also [Alternative for `[].forEach.call(…)` in ECMAScript6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30342742/1048572)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy the `.querySelector()` function returns a NodeList, and that's not a native JavaScript iterable type. You could do that if you used `Array.from()` to build a JavaScript array from the NodeList.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: [nodelists are not yet iterable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30836289/1048572)

Comment: @Pointy Where can i find the list of javascript iterable typed objects? It would be useful for me when using spread operator.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy [MDN has a list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Builtin_iterables). Anybody can define an iterable type however.

Comment: @relidon everything has a place including the for loop

Comment: @DanielA.White My problem was, when I read that the commenter rarely used the `for` loop. I thought "what? But I always use it!" then I searched and found a bunch of methods that do what the `for` loop does but with less code. Then I asked this question because I thought just as I didn't know about `map`, `filter` and a bunch  of other methods, there might be one for this specific problem.
ps - thanks to all for the clarifications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Array.from()` with `array.prototype.forEach()`:

```
Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('blockquote') ).forEach(function(quote) {
    console.log( quote );
});
```

But this is, effectively, a personal choice and entirely a matter of preference.